# Thrift IPC over pipes transport (Windows)

Tags: ipc, pipe, rpc, thrift, transport

I've been following Thrift support for Windows and VS development has come a long way thanks to a number of contributors. There are VS 2010 projects for the compiler and C++ library and I've confirmed that they work well in 0.8.
http://thrift.apache.org/download/

My question is about implementing a transport layer in Thrift, specifically pipes (named or anonymous). I've been using TCP transport which works but in cases where the apps are all local, it's overkill and generally causes other complications such as with Windows Firewall.  What I'd like to do is add pipe transport support under Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Named pipe transport has been added to Thrift. Get the development code (currently 0.8.0-dev) from SVN -- see http://thrift.apache.org/download/ for download details. It should be included in the 0.9.0 stable release assuming it doesn't break anything.

The TPipe transport now has cross-platform support for *NIX and Windows. It's implemented as named or anonymous pipes under Windows; under *NIX it uses domain sockets by leveraging TSocket. Anonymous pipes are not yet supported under *NIX. It should be relatively straight-forward to add but there doesn't seem to be demand for it.

I've also contributed a sample project that should make it easier to get started with this. The SVN trunk now has this under *thrift/contrib/transport-sample*