# Thrift: Is it possible to do only serialization with C++ Thrift library?

Tags: c++, serialization, thrift

With C++ Apache Thrift library, is it possible to use only Serialization/Deserialization and not use RPC services?

As I understand from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608531/is-there-an-ipc-transport-implementation-for-thrift-or-low-latency-soa-solutio) page, it is possible to do with Java library. However, I could not find the similar classes for C++ library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
Thrift lacks documentation about this subject. Well, about anything really.

Here i found this:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/thrift-user/201010.mbox/%3C5EF8F634-79A2-45C4-9A04-6D96D3B7A84F@manbert.com%3E

i personally use boost::serialization if there is no need to transfer data over network.
Much clear syntax and supports JSON, XML and binary output/input.

Comment: Thanks. Thrift documentation is pretty much non-existent.

Comment: In the meantime (since 2012), there is plenty of docs available. Nevertheless, there's some thruth to it w/regard to "serialization only". Alttough deriveable from the full solution with RPC, we can do better => [THRIFT-4128](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-4128)

Answer (score 4):

In c++ you can use the TFileTransport:

```
boost::shared_ptr<TFileTransport> transport(new TFileTransport(filename));
boost::shared_ptr<TBinaryProtocol> protocol(new TBinaryProtocol(transport));
yourObj.write(protocol.get()); // to write
```

or

```
yourObj.read(protocol.get()); // to read
```

Answer (score 3):

If you simply want to serialize into bytes (without having to write to a file), you can use `TMemoryBuffer`.

```
boost::shared_ptr<TMemoryBuffer> buffer(new TMemoryBuffer());
boost::shared_ptr<TBinaryProtocol> binaryProtcol(new TBinaryProtocol(buffer));

obj->write(binaryProtcol.get());
obj->read((binaryProtcol.get()));
```

Comment: Does the `obj` have to be an instance of TBase? Also, once the `obj` has been serialized to bytes using the write() call, how does one access those resulting bytes? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different mailing list post with some attached code showing how to use thrift to serialize to a file in C++.

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/thrift-user/201203.mbox/%3C90483D01-ED25-4707-9DB2-5BB3627301FC@manbert.com%3E

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this question was asked a while ago. I encountered a similar use case recently (with an additional requirement - sending the serialized bytes to a Kafka cluster). Here's my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42871143/serializing-a-thrift-struct-in-c-and-sending-it-to-kafka) with more complete code snippets that illustrate how the serialization and sending tasks can be done.

Comment: One of them is a duplicate as it is today. My recommendation would be to consider rephrasing of the other questiion in a way that makes it a non-duplicate, i.e. focusing on the Kafka part of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've reworded the other question to focus on Kafka. Let me know if more changes are required.