# Serializing a serialized Thrift struct to Kafka in C++

Tags: c++, serialization, apache-kafka, thrift

I have a set of `structs` defined in `Thrift` such as the following:

```
struct Foo {
  1: i32 a,
  2: i64 b
}
```

I need to do the following in `C++`:

(a) Serialize instances of `Foo` into Thrift-compatible bytes (either using the `Binary` or `Compact` Thrift protocol)

(b) Send the byte-serialized instances to a `Kafka` topic

**Question**

How I do send the `Thrift` serialized instances to a `Kafka` cluster?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thrift: Is it possible to do only serialization with C++ Thrift library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328896/thrift-is-it-possible-to-do-only-serialization-with-c-thrift-library)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out the answer to my own question.

## Serialization

The code snippet below illustrates how to serialize an instance of `Foo` to `Thrift`-compatible bytes (using the Thrift `Compact` protocol). In order to use the `Binary` protocol, replace `TCompactProtocol` with `TBinaryProtocol`.

```
#include <thrift/transport/TBufferTransports.h>
#include <thrift/protocol/TCompactProtocol.h>

using apache::thrift::protocol::TCompactProtocol;
using apache::thrift::transport::TMemoryBuffer;

...
...
boost::shared_ptr<TMemoryBuffer> buffer(new TMemoryBuffer());
boost::shared_ptr<TCompactProtocol> protocol(new TCompactProtocol(buffer));
uint8_t **serialized_bytes = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t **>(malloc(sizeof(uint8_t *)));
uint32_t num_bytes = 0;

// 'foo' is an instance of Foo
foo->write(protocol.get());
buffer->getBuffer(serialized_bytes, &num_bytes);
```

## Sending to Kafka cluster

The following code snippet illustrates how to send the Thrift-compatible bytes to a Kafka cluster.

**NOTE**: The kafka client library used below is [librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka).

```
#include "rdkafkacpp.h"

std::string errstr;

// Create global configuration
RdKafka::Conf *conf = RdKafka::Conf::create(RdKafka::Conf::CONF_GLOBAL);
conf->set("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092", errstr);
conf->set("api.version.request", "true", errstr);

// Create kafka producer
RdKafka::Producer *producer = RdKafka::Producer::create(conf, errstr);

// Create topic-specific configuration
RdKafka::Topic *topic = RdKafka::Topic::create(producer, "topic_name", nullptr, errstr);

auto partition = 1;

// Sending the serialized bytes to Kafka cluster
auto res = producer->produce(
    topic, partition,
    RdKafka::Producer::RK_MSG_COPY /* Copy payload */,
    serialized_bytes, num_bytes,
    NULL, NULL);

  if (res != RdKafka::ERR_NO_ERROR) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to publish message" << RdKafka::err2str(res) << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "Published message of " << num_bytes << " bytes" << std::endl;
  }

producer->flush(10000);
```

Comment: @Edenhill do we have any example of using Serialized object with C++.  All the examples in the internet uses Java with Kafka to serialize and deserialize by setting props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
  "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.protobuf.KafkaProtobufSerializer").  How to do this in C++?